# Can I use inequalities with void * in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management

If this question has already been answered, please let me know.
I am attempting to build a custom memory manager for a project.

Assume I alloc a chunk of memory:

```
void * m = malloc(1000000);
```

I divide that chunk out into smaller chunks pointing at different locations in the chunk. Something like: `void * chunk = (char *)m + x;` x being some offset from m.

When I return the chunk address back is it legal to use:

```
if(!((chunk >= m) && (chunk <= ((char*)m + x)))){
      perror("invalid address: );
      exit(-1);
}
```

Added notes: to receive and give back the memory address are separate functions so the `((char *)m + x)` is already defined outside of the if statement in a struct I built.

I have implemented it and it does seem to work. But I couldn't find any information if this is a way to ensure the proper memory address is returned back to the manager.

I am using GCC with Linux with C99.

Comment: In practice, yes.  Formally, the C Standard does not guarantee it.  There was a related question recently; the guaranteed check was painful to behold — see [Check if pointer points to given array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325787/check-if-pointer-points-to-given-array).  The trouble is that the comparisons are only valid if the pointer is in range; if it is out of range, then the comparisons are not (guaranteed to be) valid.

Comment: That's pretty cool! Thanks for the quick response. I can only imagine what the check looks like ...

Comment: Beware: modern C compilers subvert the clear intentions of programmers at the first excuse of undefined behaviour.  (See the LLVM project blog about [What every C programmer should know about undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) — in three enthralling episodes.)  Frankly, it is completely counter-productive; they're going too far.  But that's the way of the future.